# Prove how solutions of a system of linear equations are a subset of solutions of a Linear combination of the same System of Linear Equations.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let there be some system of linear equations denoted by S.L.E.

And let there a linear combination of equations from S.L.E. denoted by L.C.

Then soltuions of S.L.E. ⊆ solutions of L.C.

Prove This.

Comment: Hint: A system of equations can be written as $Ax=b$. A linear combination of them as $BAx=Bb$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have the system of linear combinations $$Ax=b,$$ where $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix of coefficients, $x$ is a $n\times 1$ vector of variables and $b$ is a $m\times 1$ vector of constants. Then any set of linear combinations of these equations can be written as $$MAx=Mb$$ for some $r\times m$ matrix $M$. If $v$ is a solution to $Ax=b$, that is if $Av=b$, then $MAv=Mb$, hence $v$ is also a solution of $MAx=Mb$.

Comment: Is M an elementary matrix ?

Comment: No it can be any matrix, depends on what linear combinations are taken

Comment: Then how can one multiply M on both sides of Ax = b if M is not an elementary matrix.